# How to convert my MySQL Connection to a Class in VB.NET 2010?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, class

I have multiple forms, each form performs specific task that requires connection to the MySQL Server.
On each form, these are declared:

```
Imports MySql.Data.SqlClient

Dim myConnObj As New MySqlConnection
```

And I use them like this:

```
myConnObj = New MySqlConnection()
myConnObj.ConnectionString = "Server=" & db_Server & ";Database=" & dbase & ";UID= & "db_UserID & ";PWD=" & db_Password
myConnObj.Open()

''Things to do here

myConnObj.Close
```

I would like to convert this process into a Class to minimize the code and it should be available thru all the forms, but I dont know where to start. 
Though I've already created an empty Class in VB named clsConnect.vb
Please note that "dbase" (the database I will connect into) should be varying.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you go take the singleton approach:

#### VB.NET:

```
Public Class DBase
    #Region "Singleton"

    Private Shared instances As New Dictionary(Of [String], DBase)()
    Public Shared Function GetInstance(dbname As [String]) As DBase
        If Not instances.ContainsKey(dbname) Then
            instances(dbname) = New DBase(dbname)
        End If
        Return instances(dbname)
    End Function

    #End Region

    Private connection As MySqlConnection

    Private Sub New(dbase As [String])
        Me.connection = New MySqlConnection()
        Me.connection.ConnectionString = "...connection string implementing dbase..."
        Me.connection.Open()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        Try
            Me.connection.Close()
        Finally
            MyBase.Finalize()
        End Try
    End Sub

    #Region "Database Methods"

    ' add the various method calls to the database here.

    #End Region
End Class

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by NRefactory.
'Twitter: @telerik, @toddanglin
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```

#### C#

```
public class DBase
{
  #region Singleton

  private static Dictionary<String, DBase> instances = new Dictionary<String, DBase>();
  public static DBase GetInstance(String dbname)
  {
    if (!instances.ContainsKey(dbname))
    {
      instances[dbname] = new DBase(dbname);
    }
    return instances[dbname];
  }

  #endregion

  private MySqlConnection connection;

  private DBase(String dbase)
  {
    this.connection = new MySqlConnection();
    this.connection.ConnectionString = "...connection string implementing dbase...";
    this.connection.Open();
  }

  ~DBase()
  {
    this.connection.Close();
  }

  #region Database Methods

  // add the various method calls to the database here.

  #endregion
}
```

Then you can access it from where ever, and make calls to it:

#### VB.NET

```
Dim db As DBase = DBase.GetInstance("DEMO")
Dim name As [String] = db.GetUsernameFromEmail("jsmith@contoso.com")
```

#### C#

```
DBase db = DBase.GetInstance("DEMO");
String name = db.GetUsernameFromEmail("jsmith@contoso.com");
```

Very crude, but gets the job done. You could get more elaborate with validating, connection checking, cleanup and (possibly) thread-safing, but I'll keep the example short and sweet.

Comment: I didn't quite understand a lot of if. What language is this?

Comment: @Ruben: that's c#, but I've converted it for easier interpreting. If you have questions about the code, just let me know.